# Audio upload not working on server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, file-upload, upload

I have an app which records and upload mic input encoding in mp3.
When I test locally, in Flash IDE, it works fine, my audio file is uploaded.

What I have tried:

- All my files are on `swf_dir` (see in the code below)
- My embed tag already have `allowScriptAcess` set to `always`;
- Already put a generic crossdomain.xml in my host root and in `swf_dir`;
- My main class already load a policy file and allow all domains (even this being unnecessary, because it's in the same server): `system.security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.host.com/swf_dir/crossdomain.xml")` and `system.Security.allowDomain("*")`

Here is the upload/encode class.

```
package 
{
    import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLRequestHeader;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import org.bytearray.micrecorder.encoder.WaveEncoder;
    import fr.kikko.lab.ShineMP3Encoder;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Marcelo de Assis
     */
    public class Mp3Helper extends EventDispatcher
    {       
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
        var LOCAL_PATH:String = "http://www.host.com/swf_dir/upload.php";   // URL used to test on Flash IDE
        var PRODUCTION_PATH:String = "upload.php";       // URL used to test on server
        var mp3Encoder:ShineMP3Encoder; 

        var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
        var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        public function Mp3Helper() 
        {
            urlRequest.url = PRODUCTION_PATH;
            urlRequest.contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + UploadPostHelper.getBoundary();
            urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            urlRequest.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader( 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache' ) );

            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        }

        function upload_s(soundByteArray: ByteArray)
        {   
            var waveEncoder:WaveEncoder = new WaveEncoder();
            var wavData:ByteArray = waveEncoder.encode(soundByteArray, 1);

            mp3Encoder = new ShineMP3Encoder(wavData);
            mp3Encoder.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, mp3EncodeComplete);
            mp3Encoder.start();
        }

        function mp3EncodeComplete(event: Event) : void 
        {           
            urlRequest.data = UploadPostHelper.getPostData("audio.mp3", mp3Encoder.mp3Data);
            urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCompleted);
        }   

        private function loaderCompleted(event: Event):void 
        {
            dispatchEvent(event);
            var fileLoader: URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
            trace("loaderCompleted: ", fileLoader.data);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you have _master policy file_ in the root http://www.host.com/crossdomain.xml? Flash Player has _master only_ meta policy by default, you have to allow other that master policy files in the master policy file.

Comment: But why do I would need it, if the SWF and the PHP are on the same host?

Comment: Oh, I missed this fact ) In case of the same domain you don't need it of course. You should add some issue details - _URLLoader_ error code, in case of security error try to turn on policy logging (PolicyFileLog = 1) in mm.cfg file (check out this article where to locate mm.cfg file http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/)

Comment: What about the server side? I would venture a guess that the problem is caused by the mismatch between the POST data you're sending and what PHP script actually expects. Try tracing the response from the server, or better yet, trace stuff in the upload script on the server to really see what's going on.

Comment: @fsbmain, those two comments helped me to solve my problem. If you write them as a answer, I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: ok, I'll add them to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of `URLLoader` security error try to turn on policy logging (`PolicyFileLog = 1`) in mm.cfg file (check out this article where to locate mm.cfg file in your OS http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/, for win7 the default log location is `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs\policyfiles.txt`), it will helps in case of `Socket` as well.